# $_SESSION is read after page reload only

Tags: php, mysql, session

I am trying to work out a few things about Sessions lately and now I need help to get a small page to work using XAMPP.

I am using 4 pages for testing purposes: 
1) `index.php` is the page where the user puts his ID and PW.
2) `logon.php` checks the database for a matching entry and redirects einter to `index.php` or `profile.php`
3) `profil.php` echoes all relevant User Data
4) `logout.php`

Test No. 1: Now as a User I do the following: I start on index.php and type in my ID and PW. Let's say my ID is 1234. Logon says that I am fine and redirects me to profil.php, showing Data for User 1234. Now I can log out, the Session gets deleted and everything seems fine.

Test No. 2: As a new user I start on `index.php`, but now my ID is 5678. `logon.php` tells me that everything is fine and redirects me to `profil.php`, but it shows the Data from the first login (1234). I can also move to other pages and come back to `profil.php`, but data will always be for User 1234 until I refresh the page (F5 or CTRL + SHIFT + R). Either way now it states the correct 5678 Data. I can log out and the Session will be destroyed again.

Here is how I handle the sessions:

`index.php`:

```
<?php
    @session_start();
?>
```

`logon.php`:

```
<?php
    @session_start();
    session_regenerate_id(true);
?>
```

`profile.php`:

```
<?php
    @session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['personal_id'])){
        header('Location: /index.php');
        exit;
    }
?>
```

`logout.php`:

```
<?php
    @session_start();
    $_SESSION = array();
    setcookie( session_name(), "", time()-3600, session_save_path() );
    session_destroy();
    session_write_close();
?>
```

All headers look like this:

```
<head>
    <title>Scheffel Shoptime</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="5;url=./index.php">
</head>
```

Can you already see where I go wrong, or do you need further information?
Thanks in advance to everyone who tries to help!

Comment: why are you using `session_regenerate_id(true);` ? Doesn't make a lot of sense and without executing that looks like it could be the problem.

Comment: why are you doing this `@session_start();`

Comment: I am still learning on how to use sessions. I browsed other pages on stackoverflow stating that i should use session_start(); on every page.

Comment: I commented session_regenerate_id(true); out, but that does not seem to be the problem. I used it to ensure a new session is used every time i log in.

Comment: Where do you actually set `$_SESSION['personal_id']`?

Comment: @Terminus $_SESSION['personal_id'] is set on logon.php as a part of the login authentification. After the check is complete, the data is stored in $_SESSION['personal_id']. As stated it works in first and second try, but on the second try only after a reload.

Comment: Gotcha. Have you checked which `SESSION_ID` is being used and the corresponding values in the session file? For the ID, use the webdev console->network tab->request headers of any page after logging in. For the session file, look for a file whose name is the session id. It'll be wherever you store session files (by default on Windows, XAMPP uses `C:\Windows\Temp`)

Comment: @Terminus Looks like the old Session is still used on the second login. How is that possible after i unset, destroy and regenerate the session?

Comment: @Akintunde I switched to `session.auto-start=0` to see, if that has something to do with my old session being used even though it should have been destroyed already. Therefore I have to call `session_start();` manually on each page to have access to the session. Also I use the @ sign to suppress a warning, if the session is already started (that is actually no longeer necessary, since auto start is turned off now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found the solution in caching problems. I was using this code in the header:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

and changed it to:

```
<?php
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

I do not know which part of the HTML version is wrong, but the PHP version works fine and thus solved my problem. Thank you very much for your ideas and input!